# Calculate no.of cells sharing same values in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

consider this dataframe,

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  T  F  T  T  T
1  T  F  F  F  T
2  F  F  F  T  T
3  F  T  T  F  F
```

How can I find the no of cells having A=F & E=T( 1 in this case) using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Compare both columns and count `True`s values by `sum`, because `True`s are processing like `1`:

```
out = ((df.A=='F') & (df.E=='T')).sum()
print (out)
1
```

Another solution if no misisng values in `A` or `E` column:

```
out = (df.A + df.E =='FT').sum()
print (out)
1
```

EDIT:

It seems there are strings repr of boolean or boolean:

```
print (df)
       A      B      C      D      E
0   True  False   True   True   True
1   True  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False   True   True
3  False   True   True  False  False

print (df.dtypes)
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
E    object
dtype: object

out = ((df.A=='False') & (df.E=='True')).sum()
print (out)
1
```

---

```
#possible convert strings repr to boolean
#df = df == 'True'
print (df)
       A      B      C      D      E
0   True  False   True   True   True
1   True  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False   True   True
3  False   True   True  False  False

print (df.dtypes)
A    bool
B    bool
C    bool
D    bool
E    bool
dtype: object

out = (~df.A & df.E).sum()
print (out)
1
```

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: it is a combination of object, bool, float64, int64

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - So `T` and `F` are numbers? Or `True` and `False` ? Ors strings `T` and `F` ?

Comment: those are objects I believe.@jezrael

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - If use `print (df.A.head(10).tolist())` what get?

Comment: dtype: object
['False', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False'] .  @jezrael

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - thank you, so need `out = ((df.A=='False') & (df.E=='True')).sum()`

Comment: Are u sure this would work? I tried and still get the same thing. It prints 0 every-time. Clearly there are entries with common values in my dataframe.

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty and `out = (~df.A & df.E).sum()` ?

Comment: No. it doesn't :( . Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - There is some problem in data, are data confidental?

Comment: Also, when I do the & thing, I get this message "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
14406    False"

Comment: The data is not confidential. It is just a part of my data mining assignment.

Comment: @PinakiRanjanMohanty - Can you share it?

Comment: Despite not being confidential, I cannot share the data( i am supposed to build a nbc using the data; hence was looking for conditional frequencies) As I said, it is a school assignment. Also thank you for being so eager to help! Really appreciate that.

Comment: You were right. There was something wrong in my data. one of the columns had attributes objects and the other one had bool. I was comparing them similarly. hence my count was always zero.